# How To Force Website to re-create a php file through any php file

Tags: .htaccess

I am Looking for such type of coding in php file in which if i delete file.php in my website then it re-creates or copy that file from the outside of /public_html/ folder and again paste it in the /public_html/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htaccess can't really do that, but maybe you can create another php file that does that, and if the first file doesn't exist let apache run the 2nd file, I don't really know how you can do a condition like this in apache, but it's easy on nginx, so I assume apache should have an equivalent to this.

Comment: Can i have that php file coding which dose that

Comment: use copy function http://us3.php.net/copy